# WinDbg and inlined functions

Tags: c++, debugging, stack, windbg

I am trying to debug a crash dump and I want to check the value of some variable on the stack. Problem is some methods have been inlined in the release build but I want to dump the variables (dv) of this.

If I go to the stack frame and do a dv command it shows me all variables for that particular function but not those within the inlined call.

I can do a uf (unassmeble function) command to see the assembly code but its a lot of work figuring things out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not generally possible in an optimized build. 
The optimizer might decide not to allocate memory to a variable, so studying the assembly code to figure out which register is the variable in is the only way.
Furthermore, if "Omit frame pointers" switch is on, the debugger wouldn't correctly show any variable allocated on stack.

You may try to add code to log variables you're interested in into a file.

Comment: Thanks. Problem with adding logging code is that the crash dump's are from a lab (reproducing is hard work), just doing some post-mortem debugging. May have to start looking at those registers!

Comment: Optimizing compilers do things far worse than this. Another common optimization is to use the same memory address for different variables at different times.

Comment: What I find interesting is that windbg (with default generating options for *.pdbs) is able to show you all functions that are on the callstack - even those that I see are inline. Local variables for inlined might be missing though, but if they are passed along the stack you can see them in previous frames. At least that happens for driver generated code

Comment: For Visual Studio 2013(Update 4) /Zo option - that is supposed to generate richer pdb-s might be in effect without manually specifying it. I am not sure about that though, only what I saw in my case - a windows c++ driver

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to figure this out through disassembly, unfortunately. If you're not already comfortable with this then it's as good a time as any to start practicing, it's a valuable skill to have for debugging tough problems.

Also, while it doesn't help you now, the PDB file format generated by Visual Studio 2012 now does a better job of tracking inline functions. Thus, in the future this particular situation should be mitigated in most cases. You can read more about the feature here:

http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/debugging-optimized-code